# Microsoft Graph beta findRooms not returning userPrincipalName

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When using the `/beta/users/xxx/findRooms` call, the API returns a list of e-mail addresses (and names).

In most cases, the e-mail address is the same as the `userPrincipalName`, and can be used for further lookups (e.g. `/v1.0/users/<email>/calendarView...`).

However, if the room is renamed, and the associated e-mail address changed:

- the `userPrincipalName` of the room will not change
- but the e-mail address will change, and this is the one returned by `findRooms`.

This means one has to do an additional lookup to convert the name or e-mail address returned to the `userPrincipalName` or `id` required for `/users/xxx/...` lookups.

It would be great if `findRooms` returned the `userPrincipalName` and/or `id` of the room and not just the name and e-mail.

Until this is fixed by Microsoft:

- is there a way to get that additional information in `findRooms`? I couldn't find one.
- is there a way to use the returned e-mail directly in `users/xxx/calendarView` when the e-mail is **not** the `userPrincipalName`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not default behavior to return userPrincipalName  all the time, so you can submit an feature request in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or vote up an existing one.

> ```
> is there a way to get that additional information in findRooms? I couldn't find one.
> ```

No. Currently there are no appropriate way

> ```
> is there a way to use the returned e-mail directly in users/xxx/calendarView when the e-mail is not the userPrincipalName?
> ```

No. To get a specific user， we must use the following endpoint(It need the userid or the userPrincipalName):

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Comment: I created a feature request in UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35680477-add-userprincipalname-or-id-microsoft-graph-beta-f